# Hоw add numbers in differents lines?

Tags: numbers

Numbers in many lines:

add numbers

```
4900
5171
5700
4033
8583
4208
2299
2199
1699
1949
1799
2199
1899
2099
2699
2499
1549
1749
1749
2049
2149
2299
2180
2349
2499
```

I want to adding all this numbers.
How I can do this?

Comment: What have tried?

Comment: I want to add all this numbers and then get average value

Comment: Yes, but what did you try that did not work?

Comment: I don't know how I can do this operation. Or is it possible in emacs from out-of-box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My favourite method for summing a column:

- Mark one corner of the rectangle
- Move point to the opposite corner
- Type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

Acting on a rectangle is useful because it still works as-is if the numbers are actually a column within a bunch of other text.

---

In more detail:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> calls `calc-dispatch` which has keys specifically for summing rectangles --
<kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>_</kbd> call `calc-grab-sum-down` and `calc-grab-sum-across` respectively.

Unlike `calc-reduce` and friends (see below) this approach does leave the end result as a vector; so you potentially then want to `calc-unpack` that with <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> if the goal is to copy the final result back to the original buffer with <kbd>y</kbd>.

(Or simply kill/yank the value from the calc buffer using regular editing commands.)

Prior to discovering the above, my approach was to grab the rectangle from the current buffer into a calc vector, and then using the general vector operation facilities.  e.g.: to sum the numbers in the marked rectangle:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> -- invokes `calc-dispatch`
- <kbd>r</kbd> -- creates a vector from the marked rectangle
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> -- invokes `calc-vector-sum` on that vector

(Or as an alternative to that last step, try <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> to see the various `calc-reduce` vector operations under the <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> prefix.)

---

You've then *commented*:

> I want to add all this numbers and then get average value

I'm guessing that by "average" you want the mean:

- Mark the rectangle -- (as above)
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> -- (as above)
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> -- invokes `calc-vector-mean` on that vector

Or use some other <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc-vector-*` command, as desired.  (Except start with <kbd>x</kbd> instead of <kbd>M-x</kbd> because calc is helpful that way.  Tangentially, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(calc)Help Commands` is a must-read when it comes to learning about `calc`.)

Comment: What does it mean "Mark one corner of the rectangle"?

Comment: Set the mark (e.g. `C-SPC`) with point at one corner of the rectangle/column of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the numbers in `(+ ...)`, that is insert `(+` at the beginning and `)` at the end, then hit <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (`eval-last-sexp`).

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(defun sum-it-up ()
"Sum the whole buffer if no active region, or just the active region (if applicable).
Copy the result to the kill ring.  The result is thrown just in case anyone needs it."
(interactive)
  (let* (draft
         (region-active-p (region-active-p))
         (reg-beg (when region-active-p (region-beginning)))
         (reg-end (when region-active-p (region-end)))
         (sum 0))
    (save-excursion
      (if reg-beg
        (goto-char reg-beg)
        (goto-char (point-min)))
      (while (re-search-forward "[0-9,-]*\\.?[0-9]+" reg-end t)
        (setq draft
          (string-to-number (replace-regexp-in-string "," "" (match-string 0))))
        (setq sum (+ sum draft))))
    (kill-new (format "%0.2f" sum))
    (message (format "%0.2f" sum))
    sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also integrate other commands to help, e.g. `awk`:

1. Mark the region containing the lines of numbers.
2. Type `M-|` ( `shell-command-on-region` ), and input `awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'`, which means summing up every lines in the region.
3. It will display the result in echo area, `72507` in this case.
4. Or if you like to replace the region with the sum, just prefix the command, i.e. `C-u M-|`.